# How to make whois query just one server?

Tags: networking, whois

From the output of `strace -e connect whois askubuntu.com` it is apparent that the command queries one server, then another. Is there a way to force `whois` query just one specific server ?

Comment: `whois` queries name servers through the DNS protocol. Which servers it queries depends on your DNS configuration. Yes you can, in principle, change that to whatever you want, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Jos Reduce clutter in the output is one reason. Learning - another reason. BTW, I don't think it's quite accurate to say it queries names through DNS protocol.  `whois` has it's own protocol https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3912  and queries go to specific whois databases, though it does use DNS to find the IP address of specific whois database. Correct me if I'm wrong there.